# Видеокарта в VM VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu

Я использую платформу для анализа данных Knime в виртуальной машине под линуксом (долгая история почему именно так), но почему-то не получается использовать видеокарту, Linux и VM VirtualBox не видят её. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? Как сделать видеокарту доступной для ubuntu?

Видеокарта Tesla K40; CUDA 8 (Knime только 8 поддерживает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCI passthrough В virtualbox пока что еще экспериментально реализована, о чем они [пишут](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97728_01/F12469/html/pcipassthrough.html) у себя в документации. Там же написано, как можно попробовать "пробросить" pci устройство с хоста в гостя.

Comment: А вы не знаете случайно, в каких виртуальных машинах PCI passthrough реализовано и корректно работает?

Comment: Гм, да похоже во всех остальных. Во всяком случае qemu точно умеет https://habr.com/ru/post/433878/ - а она практически везде используется